# XPath working in scrapy but not in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, xpath

I have an xpath which works in python-scrapy and also in the firebug extension of firefox. But, it is not working in python-selenium. The code I am using in selenium is this

```
xpath = ".//div[@id='containeriso3']/div/a[1]/@href"
browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
```

This gives an InvalidSelectorException error. Does selenium use some other xpath version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't going to get you an element. You need to take the `@href` attribute off.

Use `.//div[@id='containeriso3']/div/a[1]`

Then use `get_attribute` to get the `href` from it.